# Store module fields not visible in IE10

Tags: expresso-store, internetexplorer

I am using EE (v 2.5.2) and Store module (v 1.6.1),but CMS is not showing up many store module fields when I am using IE 10 (Version 10.0.9200.16721) many of the store module fields are not visible.
  In other browsers this works fine but I am facing issues in IE 10 only (please check the attached screen shot),can anyone please help me out??

[image]

Cheers
Nisar

Comment: This is a bug that should be reported directly to the addon developer. I'm closing this question.

Comment: Check your console to see if you have any JavaScript errors.